# Passing a value from ineractive report to number field oracle apex

Tags: javascript, oracle, oracle-apex, apex

I have an interactive report that has only one row with multiple columns as shown in the following image: [image]

and I would like to pass the record_id value which is 145 to the number field shown in the image directly. Im new to apex and thank you in advanced.

Comment: On click? Or on page load? How did you get the work details? Could you source the record ID based on the SQL that gave you the work detail?

Comment: use a dynamic action